# How to unlock database with sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

My database gets locked all the time and I don't know why.

Here's my DBHelper class:

```
class DBHelper():
    def __init__(self, db = 'db1.sqlite'):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
            self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
            print('Connection is established')
            self.conn.commit()
        except:
            return 'Connection error'
        #finally:
        #    self.conn.close()
            
    def sql_tables(self):
        self.curs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ARTICLES(Link text PRIMARY KEY, Tittle TEXT, Time TEXT, Article TEXT)")
        self.curs.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TAGS(tag_id integer PRIMARY KEY, Tag text)')
        self.curs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ARTICLES_TAG(Article_id text PRIMARY KEY, tag_id integer,  FOREIGN KEY (Article_id) REFERENCES ARTICLE(Link),FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES TAGS(tag_id))")
        self.conn.commit()
```

I get `OperationalError: database is locked`

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is likely that you made a previous failed attempt at the code in the same session and so the files are still open.   Restart your interpreter and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite is great database, but it is normally intended to be used from a single connection. The error is a hint that you tried to open it more than once, either because you create more that one `DBHelper` object, or because it is already used by another process.

If you really need multiple accesses you should consider using a heavier product like MariaDB or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using threading locks if you have multiple threads that are trying to access the same database.

```py
    def __init__(self, db = 'db1.sqlite'):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
            self.curs = self.conn.cursor()
            print('Connection is established')
            self.conn.commit()
            self.lock = threading.Lock()   # added this line
        except:
            return 'Connection error'
        
    # use this when you want to execute a line.
    # like self.execute(line)
    def execute(self, line, fetch=None):
        """
        :param line: SQL command
        :param fetch: Number to of results to return, if none or -1 returns all
        :return: The results
        """
        ret = None
        try:
            self.lock.acquire(True)  # lock
            self.cursor.execute(line)  # run command
            if not fetch or fetch == -1:
                ret = self.cursor.fetchall()
                self.data.commit()
            else:
                ret = self.cursor.fetchmany(fetch)
                self.data.commit()
            # do something
        finally:
            self.lock.release()   # release the lock after we're done
            print(f"Returning {ret}, {line}")
            return ret

    # then maybe have a function to get stuff
    def get(self, table, column, condition=None, limit=None, first=True):
        """
        :param table: database table
        :param column: What column?
        :param condition: condition of search
        :param limit: Limit the search to X results
        :param first: Return first of every result
        :return: The results
        """

        s = f"SELECT {column} FROM {table}"
        if condition: s += f" WHERE {condition}"
        if limit: s += f" LIMIT {limit}"  # create line to execute
        result = self.execute(s)  # get result
        return result if result else []  #return result
```